# Getting file path for images INTERNAL Storage

Tags: java, android, file, directory, internal-storage

[image]

My smartphone is LG G2. As you see in the picture, LG G2 uses INTERNAL STORAGE for images. OK. But what is the path for this image?

```
   File fileToUpload = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "20160525_200312.jpg");
```

I tried this one but it gives  this error.

> E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.

Comment: "As you see in the picture, LG G2 uses INTERNAL STORAGE for images" -- LG exposes a volume to the *user* that is named "internal storage". From the standpoint of the Android SDK, that is [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). The user does not have access to what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: So how to get image file in the picture?

Comment: Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`, per the upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;
```

Or

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
```

Like :

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
String fileName = "20160525_200312.jpg";

File fileToUpload  = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);
```

Comment: So what? I am newbie for files. Where to add this code I couldn't understand.

Comment: File fileToUpload = new File(  Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()+ "20160525_200312.jpg"); 

like this?

Comment: Your problem is Solved?